# How to drop observations with values in the top and bottom one percent by year in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stata

I am trying to drop observations with prices in the top and bottom one percent, by year. I have been attempting to use `dplyr`'s `group_by` function to group by `year_sold` and then `mutate()`to create a variable `to_drop` whose value is conditional on the variable `price` being between the 1st and 99th percentile. Here's what I have so far:

```
df <- df %>%  dplyr::group_by(year_sold) %>%
  mutate(to_drop = ifelse(price <= quantile(price,0.01) | price >= quantile(price,0.99),1,0))
```

However, I am not getting the quantiles of `price` grouped by year_sold. Removing `dplyr::group_by(year_sold) %>%`
doesn't seem to change my results.

I'm trying to find alternatives to Stata's very useful `bysort` command. Here's how I would have done this in Stata:

```
gen to_drop = 0
foreach y in year_sold { 
    quietly bysort `y': summarize price, detail // To get r(p1) and r(p99)
    bysort `y': replace to_drop = 1 if ! inrange(price, r(p1), r(p99))
}
```

Can someone please help me either figure out why group_by isn't working as I would expect it to, or alternatively, help me figure out another way of achieving this task in R?

Comment: Hm. Your code looks fine and works fine. I checked on `mtcars`, grouped by `cyl` and computed quantiles of `mpg`.

Comment: Try using `dplyr::mutate`. If it still doesn't work as expected consider providing a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you @stefan. I should have thought of checking my code with another dataset. I tried it with `mtcars` and `iris` and it worked with both datasets. In fact, comparing it to my Stata code, I realized that my Stata code wasn't doing what I expected it to. So I'm very glad to have caught that, with your help.

Comment: And thank you @RonakShah. Adding `dplyr::` before `mutate` fixed the problem the above code had and it now matches Neeraj's code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use base `split` and `lapply` function to get desired results.

```
library(magrittr)

 #generating data
 df <- data.frame(year = rep(c(2001,2002), each = 20), price = runif(40, 40, 100))

filterf <- function(df) {
  q <- quantile(df$price, c(.01, .99))
  df[ df$price > q[1] & df$price < q[2], ]
}

split(df, df$year) %>% lapply(., FUN = filterf) %>% Reduce(rbind, .)
```

Comment: Thank you! This code does exactly what I expect it to. And it matches the results the above code gives me (after changing `mutate` to `dplyr::mutate` above).